# Duplicate/Left over listview item at bottom of list

Tags: java, android, listview, duplicates, adapter

I am using a ExpandableListView with a custom adapter which display a list of contacts with presence status. If they are offline, then i remove the contact from the list. Vice versa, if they are online then i add them to the list. I do a `notifyDataSetChanged()` every time i add or remove a contact. What I am seeing over time is that some list view is getting duplicated at the bottom of the list. When i expand and collapse the group of these duplicate contacts, they disappear. What it looks like is that these duplicate views are already removed but they stick around and the view is recycled. What is going on?

A presence change comes via a broadcast. The extension # of the contact is in the intent's extra.

```
private class PresenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(SIGNAL_ROSTER_CHANGE)) {
            int extension = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_EXTENSION", -1);
            if (extension != -1) {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Contact contact = findContactByExtension(Integer.toString(extension));
                        if (contact != null) {
                            int presence = getPresenceForExtension(contact.getExtension());
                            if (presence == STATUS_UNKNOWN || presence == STATUS_INVISIBLE || presence == STATUS_OFFLINE) {
                                removeFromList(contact);
                            } else {
                                addToList(contact);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logic for removal: Traverse through the list and remove any instances that matches the contact. When a contact is removed from the list, check if the list is empty. If the list is empty then remove the group and the list. Here's the removal code:

```
private void removeFromList(Contact contact) {
    if (listAdapter != null) {
        // Get adapter's child items
        List<List<Contact>> adapterListOfLists = listAdapter.getContactLists();     // Child items
        Iterator<List<Contact>> listIterator = adapterListOfLists.iterator();       

        int groupIndex = 0;
        // Iterate through list to find instances of the contact
        while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
            List<Contact> listPart = listIterator.next();
            Iterator<Contact> contactIterator = listPart.iterator();

            while (contactIterator.hasNext()) {
                Contact compareContact = contactIterator.next();
                if (contact.equals(compareContact)) {
                    contactIterator.remove();
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            // Check if list is empty after removal
            if (listPart.size() == 0) {
                // Remove the list's group
                List<String> adapterGroups = listAdapter.getContactGroup();
                adapterGroups.remove(groupIndex);
                // Remove the empty list
                listIterator.remove();
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            groupIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Contacts are sorted by first name and grouped by the alphabet of the first character of their name. If the first character of the name is not a character then it's categorized under the group: "#".

Logic for adding a contact:
Check if the contact's group exists. If it exists, then the child data exists and we do a binary search of where to insert the contact. If the group doesn't exist then the child data doesn't exists. I do a binary search to find where the group belongs and create it. Then in the corresponding index for the child data, i create a new list, add the contact to the list and insert the list in the index that corresponds with its group. Here's the inserting code:

```
private void addToList(Contact contact) {
    String contactName;
    String indexKey = "#";

    if (contact.getFirstName().length() > 0) {
        contactName = contact.getFirstName();
    } else {
        contactName = contact.getLastName();
    }

    if (contactName.length() > 0 && Character.isLetter(contactName.charAt(0))) {
        indexKey = Character.toString(contactName.charAt(0));
    }

    insertContact(contact, indexKey);
}

private void insertContact(Contact contact, String group) {
    if (listAdapter != null) {
        List<List<Contact>> adapterListOfLists = listAdapter.getContactLists();
        List<String> adapterGroups = listAdapter.getContactGroup();

        String capitalizeFirstLetter = group.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());

        group = capitalizeFirstLetter;

        int groupIndex = adapterGroups.indexOf(group);

        if (groupIndex == -1) {
            int insertGroupTitleIndex = Collections.binarySearch(adapterGroups, group, new GroupTitleComparator());

            if (insertGroupTitleIndex < 0) {
                insertGroupTitleIndex = -insertGroupTitleIndex - 1;
            }

            adapterGroups.add(insertGroupTitleIndex, group);

            List<Contact> newList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
            newList.add(contact);
            adapterListOfLists.add(insertGroupTitleIndex, newList);
        } else {
            List<Contact> groupList = adapterListOfLists.get(groupIndex);
            int insertIndex = Collections.binarySearch(groupList, contact, new ContactComparator(sortType.SORT_BY_FIRST_NAME);

            if (insertIndex < 0) {
                insertIndex = -insertIndex - 1;
            }

            groupList.add(insertIndex, contact);
        }
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Here's my getGroupView() for the adapter:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    GroupViewHolder groupHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.directory_alphabet_title, parent, false);

        groupHolder = new GroupViewHolder();
        groupHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_title);
        groupHolder.childrenCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_title_child_count);

        convertView.setTag(groupHolder);
    } else {
        groupHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (getChildrenCount(groupPosition) > 0) {
        groupHolder.title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        groupHolder.childrenCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        groupHolder.title.setText((String) getGroup(groupPosition));
        groupHolder.childrenCount.setText(Integer.toString(getChildrenCount(groupPosition)));
    } else { // If contactGroup has no contactLists then hide it
        groupHolder.title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        groupHolder.childrenCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

getChildView():

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ChildViewHolder childHolder;

if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_contact, parent, false);

    childHolder = new ChildViewHolder();

    childHolder.contactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
    childHolder.statusIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status_icon);

    convertView.setTag(childHolder);
} else {
    childHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

final Contact contact = (Contact) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

if (contact.getContactType().equals("corporate")) {
    int presence = 0;

    presence = getPresenceForExtension(contact.getExtension());

    switch (presence) {
    case STATUS_ONLINE:
        childHolder.statusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_available);
        break;
    case STATUS_BUSY:
        childHolder.statusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_busy);
        break;
    case STATUS_DND:
        childHolder.statusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_dnd);
        break;
    case INCALL:
        childHolder.statusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_oncall);
        break;
    case AWAY:
        childHolder.statusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_away);
        break;
    case STATUS_UNKNOWN:
    case STATUS_OFFLINE:
    case STATUS_INVISIBLE:
    default:
        childHolder.statusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_status_invisible);
        break;
    }
}

childHolder.contactName.setText(contact.getName());

childHolder.contactName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Open detail page of this contact
    }
});

childHolder.callButton.setFocusable(false);
childHolder.chatButton.setFocusable(false);
childHolder.favoriteButton.setFocusable(false);
return convertView;
```

}

The group and child data for the adapter, located inside the adapter class:

```
private List<List<Contact>> contactLists;
private List<String> contactGroup;

public List<List<Contact>> getContactLists() {
    return contactLists;
}

public void setContactLists(List<List<Contact>> contactLists) {
    this.contactLists = contactLists;
}

public List<String> getContactGroup() {
    return contactGroup;
}

public void setContactGroup(List<String> contactGroup) {
    this.contactGroup = contactGroup;
}
```

Update: The only alternative I've found is saving the location of the first visible item. Then create a new adapter with the modified list, set it to the listview, and then move back to the position of the first visible item recorded earlier. Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: @ElodieFerrais Hi. I added a stripped down version of it.

Comment: Sorry @kyrax I cannot reproduce your bugwith the code you gave me. If your project is on a github project I can take a look at it.

Comment: @ElodieFerrais Unfortunately, I do not. The issue does not appear at first sight. I left my device to idle while the contacts' presences are updating, and around 10-20 minutes later, I come back to the discover the duplicates at the bottom of the list. I will update if I find anything new but I greatly appreciate you looking at this. Thank you.